# Enable Timer interrupt after generating N pulse

Tags: stm32

I need to enable a general timer interrupt after generating each pulse in PWM mode. I wrote this program. I will be grateful if you kindly let me know how to enable timer interrupt. This my SPL schematic code:

```
 void PWMControl(unsigned int Freq){
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef     TimeStructureure; 
TIM_OCInitTypeDef       TIMOCStructureure;  
        
        TimeStructure.TIM_Prescaler=Prescale;
        TimeStructure.TIM_CounterMode=TIM_CounterMode_Up;
        TimeStructure.TIM_Period=Period;
        TimeStructure.TIM_ClockDivision=TIM_CKD_DIV1;
        TimeStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter=0;
        TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &TimeStructure);
        TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);  
    
        TIMOCStructure.TIM_OCMode=TIM_OCMode_PWM2;
        TIMOCStructure.TIM_OutputState=TIM_OutputState_Enable;
        TIMOCStructure.TIM_OCPolarity=TIM_OCPolarity_Low;
        TIMOCStructure.TIM_Pulse=Pulse;
        TIM_OC1Init(TIM4, &TIMOCStructure);
        //TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);     
        TIM_ITConfig(TIM4,TIM_IT_Update,ENABLE);    
    
}
```

According to [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541521/generate-n-pulse-with-a-fix-frequency-stm32f107)  I need to generate N pulse without/ the least CPU workload. (Max Frequency=1MHz)

Comment: Do you have a code for the interrupt service routine?

Comment: What library are you using? This does not look like the ST HAL drivers.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the post content.

Comment: I have added the interrupt code but it doesn't work. It just generate a continuous PWM wave form.

Comment: 1 MHz is a high frequency for interrupts. You need to use method 3 from the linked question. You need to chain 2 timers, and enable interrupts in the slave timer so that it can stop the master timer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Could you introduce me a reference which covers the master and slave Timers with SPL?

Comment: I don't know SPL or HAL, but you can search for **Timer synchronization** in reference manual. It provides steps to configure timers in master-slave configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CubeMX?

If yes then you have to first enable it in NVIC after configuring TIM4.

Next, inside your logic you have to enable the timer as HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_1);